# How to compare a word is it found in table rows?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this PostgreSQL table for storing words:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS words
(
    id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('processed_words_id_seq'::regclass),
    keyword character varying(300) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
);

insert into words (keyword)
VALUES ('while swam is interesting');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS trademarks
(
   id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('trademarks_id_seq'::regclass),
   trademark character varying(300) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
);
```

Into table `trademarks` I will have thousands of registered trademarks names.
I want to compare words stored into `words` table keyword, do they match not only for a words but also for word which is in a group of words. For example:

I have a keyword `while swam is interesting` stored into `words.keyword`. I also have a trademark `swam` located in `trademarks.trademark` I have a word match, so I want to detect this using SQL.

I tried this:

```
select 
    w.id, w.keyword, t.trademark 
from
    words w
inner join 
    trademarks t 
on
  t.trademark ilike  '%'||w.keyword||'%' 
where 
   w.keyword = 'all';
```

But I get this result:

[image]

As you can see, the result is wrong. I need to match complete words, not parts of the words. How I can fix this?

Comment: can you share the sample scripts please-> for the trademarks table and the words table

Comment: Sounds like you should use a regular expression on word boundaries instead of `%` with no space before/after the search word https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-SIMILARTO-REGEXP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the words field on space to create an array, then use `any` twice: once for the `where` (ie "any words list containing 'all') and once for the match (ie any trademark that appears in a words list that also contains 'all'):

```sql
select 
    w.id,
    w.keyword,
    t.trademark 
from words w
join trademarks t on t.trademark =
  any(string_to_array(w.keyword, ' '))
where 'all' = any(string_to_array(w.keyword, ' '))
```

This matches the *whole* word, so no need to worry about word boundaries etc.

---

You can tidy this up and improve performance with a CTE that `unnests` the words:

```sql
with w as (
    select
        id,
        keyword,
        unnest(string_to_array(keyword, ' ')) as term
    from words
    where 'all' = any(string_to_array(keyword, ' '))
)
select 
    w.id,
    w.keyword,
    t.trademark 
from w
join trademarks t on t.trademark = w.term
```

Add indexes to make this fly:

```
create index words_keywords_index on words using gin (keyword);
create index trademarks_trademark_index on trademarks(trademarks);
```

`gin` indexes index nested values.

Comment: Thanks, looks like the solution works. Any idea how I can make it faster?

Comment: I tested the first query. It's working but very slow because I have 30 millions of rows. Any idea how to optimize it?

Comment: @PeterPenzov i moved the `where` clause into the CTE - try the bottom query now. You would get better performance and simpler queries if you created a version of the words table with 1 word per row.

Comment: Can you show me how this can be implemented using full text search?

Comment: the above query takes 7-8 seconds to execute with database with 30 millions of rows. Other solutions?

Comment: @PeterPenzov try the new version of the bottom query. Note the index you'll need to define to make this perform well.

Comment: Maybe I need 2 indexes because table `trademarks` has only 120 rows and table `words` has 30 million or rows?

Comment: @PeterPenzov See if the new index on words helps

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use regular expression as richyen mentions.
If you need to use sql what you have got is correct, except you need to look for a pattern that uses the conditions '%**SPACE**'||w.keyword||'**SPACE**%'

```
select w.id, w.keyword, t.trademark 
  from words w
  join trademarks t 
    on w.keyword like '% '||t.trademark||' %' 
 where t.trademark = 'all'
union all /*condition when there are only single words without a space*/
select w.id, w.keyword, t.trademark 
  from words w
  join trademarks t 
    on w.keyword =t.trademark
 where t.trademark = 'all';
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/k5bYAPUh

Comment: Your answer is working but I found one issue. If I have just a single keyword `ibm` and I try to find it I get a empty result which is not correct. I should get a match for the keyword `ibm`. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: One option is to use UNION ALL statement for "exact" matches with the condition on w.keyword=t.trademark

Comment: Yes it's working but it takes quite a lot to execute. Any possible idea how to optimize it?

Comment: in scenariors like these i suggest using full text search than using regular sql. https://www.compose.com/articles/indexing-for-full-text-search-in-postgresql/#:~:text=GIN%20(which%20stands%20for%20Generalized,facilitates%20rapid%20matching%20and%20retrieval.

Comment: Can you show me how this can be implement, please?

Comment: Check the above link i mentioned, another good alternative posted by @Bohemian

Answer (score 0):

You can split the keyword into a array then later compare if the trademark is inside of the splited array.

```
select 
    w.id, w.keyword, t.trademark 
from
    words w
inner join 
    trademarks t 
on
  t.trademark = ANY( string_to_array(REPLACE(w.keyword , ' ' , '~^~' ),'~^~' , '') )
where 
   w.keyword = 'all';
```

trademark and keywords overlaps each other example:

```
SELECT
ARRAY['swam'] && string_to_array(REPLACE('while swam is interesting',' ','~^~'), '~^~' ,'');
```

keywords is inside of trademark example

```
SELECT
ARRAY['swam'] @> string_to_array(REPLACE('while swam is interesting',' ','~^~'), '~^~' ,'');
```

Comment: Are you sure? it's not working.